# Is it possible call Include() with invalid characters (?) in System.Web.Optimization.Bundle?

Tags: .net, asp.net-optimization

I was trying to include a URL to a Bundle that requires a parameter to genereate the script, as such:

```
scriptBundle = BundleConfig.GetBundle("~/js/").
               Include("~/Handlers/culture.ashx?c=pt-br");
```

The problem is that it throws an exception because '?' is not a valid character. I trie URL encoding, but had no sucess. Is there anyway to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no such way to resolve this issue.